# C++ looping issue

Tags: c++

I have some code that is reading a file. I have an array that has size of 3 so I need part of my code to loop 3 times. I need help making this nested loop work in the way I want it.
As of now it works for what I need it to do just not in the middle.

the goal is to have "somevairable" count to 3

```
for(int w=0; w < weeks;w++)
{   
        for(int a =0; a < 5; a++)
       {
             /* this should loop 3 times 
        {
            total_weekly_sales[somevariable] +=  weekly_sales[0][w][a];
        {
            */
          }

  }
```

Comment: Write another loop. Or unroll the body manually if the loop is going to have one statement.

Comment: Introduce another loop if you mean something within your second loop should loop three times. If you mean your second loop should loop 3 times as against 5 iterations mentioned in the condition, either introduce break statement when your condition is met or modify the condition such that it loops for only 3 times.

Comment: It sounds like you need to review looping constructs and arrays in C++, you should take some time and read the tutorials at cprogramming.com: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c++-tutorial.html

Comment: It seems easy but the way I have the whole thing layerd out makes it a headache using a counter made it more simple. I just was trying to avoid any more nest messes.

Comment: 'nest messes' are part of programming. One way to avoid them is to split your code into smaller chunks by writing more functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
for(int w=0; w < weeks;w++)
{   

        for(int a=0; a < 5; a++)
       {
             for(int somevariable=0; somevariable < 3; somevariable++) 
             {
                total_weekly_sales[somevariable] +=  weekly_sales[0][w][a];
             }

       }

}
```

Comment: in my program this assigns the same variables to all 3 sections of the array

Comment: It depends on what weekly_sales[0][w][a] stored. the way i see it, when loop end you your total_weekly_sales array will store same value as weekly_sales[0][w][5], weekly_sales[0][w][5] and weekly_sales[0][w][5] ... all the same value. You may consider change the logic.

Comment: Ok got it i just added the counter to the first part of the 3d array as well. It was over just repeating on 0 the whole time. The problem in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 0;
for(int w=0; w < weeks;w++)
{   
    for(int a =0; a < 5; a++)
   {
         /* this should loop 3 times */
    {
        total_weekly_sales[count % 3] +=  weekly_sales[0][w][a];
        ++count;
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: This works. Its because it avoids another nest that it wont just fill the array over and over.